# Interpreting WPF Dependency properties as a set

Tags: .net, wpf, dependency-properties

So, I have a control. It displays an image based some xml document and an optional parameter

- "Document" - XML document
- "RenderingOption" -  optional image-rendering ( sharpen, soften )

So:

```
<XMLRenderingWidget Document="xxxxxx"/>
```

The above will render the document once

```
<XMLRenderingWidget Document="xxxxxx" RenderingOption="Sharpen"/>
```

The above will, sometimes render the document once, more oftentimes:

- Perform the rendering of the document as if no Rendering was set
- then, re-render the document with the Sharpen option

I do the rendering on the PropertyChangedCallback assigned to the property.
How do I tell the control to "hey, before doing the rendering, apply the changes on the other properties being set, too"

Is this not possible? Should I bundle them up as one property instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try defering the execution with

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(DoRender), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
```

dispatcher will finish updating properties before executing your action.